# SWIFT: How to add key value on existing child by clicking on save button?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new with Firebase and Swift so I need solution.
I have table view with list of guests. When I select guest (one or more), and then save, how can I add the "table number" from text field into the guest(autoID) array which is already exist? Here is photo from Firebase how it looks.

[image]

Comment: The most important thing is that you *must* already know the auto-ID of the node you want to update. So you'll have to track that when you *read* from the database, and pass it along when the user clicks on the button. But aside from that it's really hard to help without seeing what you've already tried.

Comment: is this firebase realtime database ? If yes click on that blank part in which you want to update it will make edit space for you. Edit blank value with number you want and click enter value will be updated in db

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's a document for each reservation, the structure would look like this

```
reservations //the collection
  res_0      //the document
    guestName: "Nick"
    tableNo: ""
```

so the associated code to update the tableNo field would look like this

```
db.collection("reservations").document("res_0").setData([
    "tableNo": "3"
], merge: true) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully written!")
    }
}
```

That's pretty well covered in the documentation [Add data To Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) so take a look!